# MPU6050 - Why is my gyro integration incorrect?

Tags: i2c, mpu6050

My situation:

- I am able to communicate over i2c with my MPU6050 IMU
- I can get accelerometer and gyro data
- I can compute the sensor's orientation using my accelerometer

Issue:

- when trying to compute the sensor's orientation using my gyroscope my values seem to be totally incorrect. I am computing the orientation using a [complementary filter](https://www.pieter-jan.com/node/11).

This is the code I use https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vZmbnc23gj/

This is the computed orientation, when the sensor is lying on a table: https:https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/W7DzVKR9c7/
Those measurements are totally incorrect, because when moving the senor randomly around its axis it never goes above 1.8. (even when I do an 180 degree turn)

Could somebody give me some hints or explanation on why my results are incorrect and drifting so much?

Comment: Could you post a schematic of your connections? I understand you can communicate with it, but am interested in what you have.

Comment: @Wendall connection, are just typical "i2c connection" without pull ups

Answer (score -1):

You need to perform offset calibration, otherwise you'll get large drift errors. The MPU6050 has a dedicated Digital Motion Processor (DMP) where data from the gyro and accelerometer are fused for you. I recommend grabbing the results of that fusion from the DMP. As far as I know the only libraries that do this are ones based on Jeff Rowberg's work. For a detailed guide please see:

https://youtu.be/k5i-vE5rZR0